# select top 5 group by country in Laravel

Tags: laravel, charts

I have following model (migration below) pulling out chart with countries which visited my site.
How can I pull out only top 10 countries?
Thank you

```
return Charts::database(Visit::all(), 'donut', 'highcharts')
        ->title('Requests by country')
        ->dimensions(700, 300)
        ->responsive(true)
        ->groupBy('country');
```

This is my table

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamp('timestamp');
        $table->ipAddress('ip_address');
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('details')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use order by

```
return Charts::database(Visit::all(), 'donut', 'highcharts')
        ->title('Requests by country')
        ->dimensions(700, 300)
        ->responsive(true)
        ->groupBy('country')
        ->orderBy('column_name','asc')  
        ->take(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the info already filtered, something like this:

```
$info = DB::table('visits')
       ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as country_count, country'))
       ->groupBy('country')
       ->orderBy('country_count', 'desc')
       ->take(10)
       ->get();

return Charts::database($info, 'donut', 'highcharts')
    ->title('Requests by country')
    ->dimensions(700, 300)
    ->responsive(true);
```